# Failed precondition errors when using keras model in C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

We have created a simple Keras model in tensorflow 2.0 (Python 3.6.8):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense

def create_model():
    input = Input([416, 416, 3], name='input')
    x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1),
               activation='relu')(input)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = Dense(10, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(6, activation='softmax', name='output')(x)
    return Model(input, x, name='mymodel')
```

then saved it with

```py
model = create_model()
tf.saved_model.save(model, "/tmp/saved_model")
```

Running the tensorflow command line tool

```
saved_model_cli show --dir /tmp/saved_model --all
```

we can inspect the model:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['__saved_model_init_op']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['__saved_model_init_op'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: NoOp
  Method name is: 

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['input'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 416, 416, 3)
        name: serving_default_input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['output'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 101, 101, 6)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Next, we want to load the model and run inference in C++ with the following code:

```cpp
tf::Status status{};
status = tf::NewSession(tf::SessionOptions(), &m_session);
tf::GraphDef graph_def;
tf::MetaGraphDef meta_graph_def;
status = tf::ReadMetaGraphDefFromSavedModel("/tmp/saved_model", {"serve"}, &meta_graph_def);
graph_def = meta_graph_def.graph_def();
status = m_session->Create(graph_def);

const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, tf::Tensor>> input_nodes = {{"serving_default_input:0", input}};
const std::vector<std::string> output_nodes = {"StatefulPartitionedCall:0"};
std::vector<tf::Tensor> outputs = {};

// run the session
const auto operationStatus = m_session->Run(input_nodes, output_nodes, {}, &outputs);
```

However, we keep running into the same problem:

```
Status failed Failed precondition: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable conv2d/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/conv2d/kernel)
     [[{{node mymodel/conv2d/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp}}]]
     [[StatefulPartitionedCall/_27]]
  (1) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable conv2d/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/conv2d/kernel)
     [[{{node mymodel/conv2d/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

Has anyone seen this before, and does anyone know why this happens?